# Xtext hover - Is there a way to show all information in an object including the keywords and other object

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

Say, I have a variable which when hovered on I should be able to show the complete variable declaration information including keywords and objects. For example if I have a rules like

```
DataEntry:  "VAR" v=Varname  init+=Initialise*';'; 
Varname : name = ID;
Initialise : "=" INTEGER;
```

So now if i hover over a instance of a varname where the definition is as below

```
VAR num1 = 0;
```

Then I should be able to show the complete definition as shown above, in the hover. How can I achieve this? I know there are separate process for getting objects and separate one for keywords, is there something where I can get all that is set in DataEntry rule irrespective of keywords and objects?

Thanks,
Anitha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
    EObject o = ...;
    NodeModelUtils.findActualNodeFor(o).getText();
```

to obtain the node model and its text.

Comment: In continuation, the hover description is stripping off the newlline characters and spaces. Not sure how it;s done. I would like to keep the formatting as is.